# pass value from html page to android activity page in phone gap

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview

I am using phone gap API in my android project and I want to pass a value from the HTML page to android activity.

I have ready few post in stack overflow but some are relevant and some are not working. Is there any way of doing this ?

Thanks